# Few headers in recycler view in android

Tags: android

I have List with objects where I have filds like: complete, incomplete, continue. 
I want to sort my list on this three sections. 
First I want to add header: INCOMPLETE and all elements if this field is true. After that I want to add header COMPLETE and again elements but with field complete is true, etc. 
This is possible in recycler view? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe android doesn't have such control. You've just described ios table view control. Probably you'll have to search for a custom sectioned recycler view control.
For example, check out the following component https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2921

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11439015)

Comment: Have you looked at the link? Do you suggest to attach github sources here? https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the easiest way to achieve this would be to have 3 recyclerviews in your layout!

Then simply add items to each view based on the three sections.

Now, to add headers, you simply have textviews that have the STATUS of the items i.e COMPLETE, etc

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). You can group your items into sections and add a header to each section:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the sorted list of data
MySection incompleteSection = new MySection("", incompleteList);
MySection completeSection = new MySection("", completeList);

// add your sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(incompleteSection);
sectionAdapter.addSection(completeSection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```